# Ordenar un objeto Date que se obtiene con un Fetch desde una API a un fichero JSON

Tags: javascript, json, date, objeto, fetch

Muy buenas chicos tengo este fichero html, donde "casco" todo el código para hacer unas pruebas de speech-to-text.

Al final tengo unos datos de tipo fecha (in promise) que quiero ordenar para que al mostrarlos puedan ser legibles. Me vale con cualquier método, al final lo que no consigo es que ordene la fecha de cumpleaños y la fecha de visita. Los métodos los tengo localizados, el que mejor "me viene" es "[toDateString()](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toDateString)" pero no consigo pintarlo como quiero.

Al final quiero que dentro de una de las cards creadas se muestren los 4 datos que recojo desde el micrófono, se tratan en un swagger (API) y nos devuelve un JSON con unos datos seleccionados por un bot, pero solo recoge la fecha de visita, la fecha de nacimiento, el nombre y un número que corresponde a una posición. Con mostrar la fecha correctamente me vale.

¿Podéis echarme una mano?

Muchas gracias de antemano ;)

Dejo adjunto el codigo del JSON aquí;

```
{
  "suggestedBirthDayDate": [
    "1993-04-01"
  ],
  "suggestedBodySite": [
    "14"
  ],
  "suggestedDevice": [
    "Straumann BLX"
  ],
  "suggestedEncounterDate": [
    "2022-05-11"
  ],
  "suggestedPatients": [
    "Francisco Ferre"
  ]
}
```

```js
    window.SpeechRecognition = window.webkitSpeechRecognition || window.SpeechRecognition;
    const recognition = new SpeechRecognition();


    const icon = document.querySelector('i.fa.fa-microphone')
    let paragraph = document.createElement('p');
    let container = document.querySelector('.text-box');
    container.appendChild(paragraph);

    icon.addEventListener('click', () => {
        dictate();
    });

    // Set Speech Language
    recognition.lang = "es-ES";

        const BASE_URL = 'http://localhost:8080/api/speech/#/';


    const dictate = () => {
        recognition.start();
        recognition.onresult = (event) => {
            event.results = undefined;
            paragraph.textContent = event.results[0][0].transcript;
            postData(BASE_URL, {text: paragraph.textContent})
                .then(data => {
                    console.log(data);
                    document.getElementById("nombrePaciente").innerHTML = JSON.stringify(data.suggestedPatients);
                    document.getElementById("fechaNacimientoPaciente").innerHTML = JSON.stringify(data.suggestedBirthDayDate[0]);
                    document.getElementById("fechaCitaPaciente").innerHTML = JSON.stringify(data.suggestedEncounterDate[0]);
                    document.getElementById("dientePaciente").innerHTML = JSON.stringify(data.suggestedBodySite[0])
                    //document.getElementById("modeloProducto").innerHTML = JSON.stringify(data.suggestedBodySite)
                })
        }

        async function postData(url = '', data = {}) {
            const response = await fetch(url, {
                method: 'POST',
                headers: {
                    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
                },
                body: JSON.stringify(data)
            });
            return response.json()
        }

    }
```

```css
body {
    background: #f2f2f2;
    margin: 0;
    font-family: sans-serif;
}
.header {
    background-color: #000;
    color: #fff;
    display: flex;
}

.logoBox {
    border-right: 1px solid #ececec;
    height: 95%;
}
.logo {
    max-width: 200px;
    padding: 0 3rem;
}
.titleLogo {
    font-size: 1.5rem;
    padding: 1rem 5rem;
}
.container {
    margin: 1rem;
}
.text-box {
}
.text-box:focus {
    outline: none;
}
.text-box p {
}
.microTextToSpeech {
    margin: 5px;
    padding: 5px;
    font-size: 16px;
    font-weight: 200;
    position: absolute;
    right: 8rem;
    bottom: 2rem;
    width: 250px;
}
.fa {
    color: white;
    background: #000;
    border-radius: 50%;
    cursor: pointer;
    width: 5rem;
    height: 5rem;
    margin: 0.5rem;
    display: flex !important;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    font-size: 2rem !important;
    animation: pulse-animation 2s infinite;
    position:absolute;
    bottom:1rem;
    right:1rem;
}

.fa:hover {
    background: #fff;
    color: #000;
    border: 1px solid #000;
    transition: 0.5s;
    transform: perspective(1px) translateZ(0);
}

@keyframes pulse-animation {
    0% {
        box-shadow: 0 0 0 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
    }
    100% {
        box-shadow: 0 0 0 20px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
    }
}

.cardPatient {
    background: #fff;
    border-radius: 0.5rem;
    box-shadow: 0 0.5rem 1rem rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
    padding: 1rem;
    margin: 1rem;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: space-between;
    animation: loading-indicator-rotation 3s linear infinite;
    max-width: 450px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Speech Recognition MADTeam</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
</head>
<body>
<header class="header">
    <div class="logoBox">
        <img src="straumann_logo_white.png" alt="logo" class="logo">
    </div>
    <h1 class="titleLogo">Speech Recognition MADTeam</h1>
</header>
<div class="container">
    <div class="text-box" contenteditable="true">
        <p id="mostrarData"></p>
    </div>
    <div class="cardPatient">
        <p id="nombrePaciente"></p>
        <p id="fechaNacimientoPaciente"></p>
        <p id="fechaCitaPaciente"></p>
        <p id="dientePaciente"></p>
        <p id="modeloProducto"></p>
    </div>
    <div class="d-flex">
        <i class="fa fa-microphone"></i>
        <p class="cardPatient microTextToSpeech">Hi Doc! <br> Please click on the microphone to speech the treatment</p>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Una imagen del resultado de la consulta y como "pinta" los datos.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: ¿Y cómo sería el formato en que deseas mostrar dicha fecha? ¿Puedes dar un ejemplo del JSON que recibes? ¿Qué criterio deseas usar para ordenar?

Comment: @MauricioContreras, lo adjunto a la pregunta. Así es más facil. Gracias por responder!

Comment: De las 3 cosas que te pedí aclaraciones sólo has agregado una. Falta: criterio de ordenamiento (ascendente, descendente) y qué campo será el que defina ese ordenamiento. Formato de fecha que deseas mostrar, no lo específicas. El JSON recibido parece que tiene los campos de fecha en formato cadena, es correcto? Basado en eso, cuál sería la salida que esperas para dichos campos?

Comment: @MauricioContreras. Cuando hablo de ordenar, es solo una fecha, asi que me imagino que es normalizar la fecha para que se muestre con el día (Monday, Tuesday, etc.)-mes y año. La idea, es leer una cita de un paciente: "XXXX con fecha de cumpleaños XXXX a venido a la consulta día XXXX para la extracción del diente XX", recoge las incognitas y las muestra sin más. Las fechas normalizadas. Si llegan así "2017-05-25" mostrarla así: 25 de Mayo de 2017; el resto de datos se muestran bien...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Si necesita cambiar el formato de las fechas le recomiendo el plugin **dayjs**.

https://github.com/iamkun/dayjs/

¿Puede ser algo similar a esto lo que necesitas?

**HTML:**

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/dayjs/1.11.2/dayjs.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/dayjs/1.11.2/locale/es.min.js"></script>

<div>
  <p>
    El día <span id="suggestedEncounterDate"></span>, ha venido <span id="suggestedPatients"></span>, a la consulta para la extración del diente <span id="suggestedBodySite"></span> y su fecha de cumpleaños, el <span id="suggestedBirthDayDate"></span>.
  </p>
</div>
```

**JavaScript:**

```
dayjs.locale('es');

const data = {
  "suggestedBirthDayDate": [
    "1993-04-01"
  ],
  "suggestedBodySite": [
    "14"
  ],
  "suggestedDevice": [
    "Straumann BLX"
  ],
  "suggestedEncounterDate": [
    "2022-05-11"
  ],
  "suggestedPatients": [
    "Francisco Ferre"
  ]
};

const suggestedBirthDayDate = dayjs(data.suggestedBirthDayDate[0]).format('DD MMMM YYYY');
const suggestedEncounterDate = dayjs(data.suggestedEncounterDate[0]).format('DD MMMM YYYY');

document.getElementById("suggestedBirthDayDate").textContent = suggestedBirthDayDate;
document.getElementById("suggestedBodySite").textContent = data.suggestedBodySite[0];
document.getElementById("suggestedEncounterDate").textContent = suggestedEncounterDate;
document.getElementById("suggestedPatients").textContent = data.suggestedPatients[0];
```

https://jsfiddle.net/romeroedward18/957nr4zq/24/

Comment: Gracias @Edward!! me ha venido fantástico para aplicarlo a una parte del código !!!

Comment: @SergioEscobales  me alegro un montón que te haya servido 